# SQL - cannot perform distinct count when joining two tables

Tags: sql, left-join, distinct

I have two tables: Customers and Orders. I do a left join of Customers and Orders on CustomerID column which is primary key in Customers and foreign key in Orders.

1. When I list CustomerID after joining, I get the list as expected.
2. When I count the number of CustomerID, again I get the number of record I am expecting.
3. When I use distinct count for CustomerID, i get an error.

1.

```
select  Customers.CustomerID as list
from Customers left join Orders on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
where Customers.CustomerID = 4;
```

2.

```
select  count(Customers.CustomerID) as numRecord
from Customers left join Orders on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
where Customers.CustomerID = 4;
```

3.

```
select  count(distinct (Customers.CustomerID)) as numRecord
from Customers left join Orders on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
where Customers.CustomerID = 4;
```

I cannot understand where is the error. Any help would be appreciated.
The error:

```
Error in SQL:
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(distinct Customers.CustomerID)'.
```

Comment: which db you are using?

Comment: I am just running the queries on this link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need  the () around  Customers.CustomerID in count(distinct  ..)

```
select  count(distinct Customers.CustomerID) as numRecord
from Customers 
left join Orders on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
where Customers.CustomerID = 4;
```

Comment: even without (), there is an error. I put () to check if there is no error

Comment: Please check Error. The database is from www.w3schools.com. The link for database is: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner

Comment: I have just tried  and work  ... return (obviusly) 1 ... could be you need  clear you cache on reset you browser ..

Comment: It did not work in firefox but worked in Chrome. Thanks